# How to make background's color transition on a react component?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-animations, compass-sass

I simply want to set up a background fadeout animation when a new message is posted in the page.

I just want the background to change. from blue to opacity 0.

Just a basic animation when a new post is added in the page in real time.

I've tried this but it doesn't work, when i add the message, the background color remains blue.

I am using reactJS coupled with SASS/Compass

```js
<div className="successfully-saved"><Message /></div>
```

```css
.successfully-saved{
  background-color:blue;
  @include transition(opacity, 1s ease-out);
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Is the successfully-saved the post or the main page?

Comment: So basically you want to display the message and once post is saved fade out(hide) the message.Right?

Comment: @hunzaboy Only the post component

Comment: @Dev Actually i set up my app so that once i submit the form, the componnent is append directly in the page without any refresh, but i need to make an animation fadeout to let the user know that some fresh content has been added.

Comment: @Johndoe, I have added the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Assuming, you want to fadeout/hide message, when a new post is successfully added. You can change the style of the div and set opacity to 0. Something like this. Hope this helps.

```js
let msgEl = document.getElementById('msg');

//To add post successfully, I am just using setTimeout. It may vary in your case.
setTimeout(function() {
   msgEl.innerHTML = "Post Successfully Added";
   msgEl.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
}, 1000)
```

```css
.successfully-saved{
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: background-color 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="msg" class="successfully-saved"></div>
```

Comment: Hey ! thanks you. I was seeking something like this. However i need the opacity transition be operated only for the background color. Because by using this example, my entire component disappear. How can i fix this ? thanks.

Comment: You don't want to hide the message? I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much ! works exactly as expected. I couldn't hope a better result. Thanks for your helping. Solved !